# Unnest a data frame and fill new rows with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, unnest

Let's say I have a nested df, and I want to unnest the columns:

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~x, ~y, ~nestdf,
    1,  2,  tibble::tibble(a=1:2, b=3:4),
    3,  4,  tibble::tibble(a=3:5, b=5:7)
)
tidyr::unnest(df, nestdf)

#      x     y     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1     3
#2     1     2     2     4
#3     3     4     3     5
#4     3     4     4     6
#5     3     4     5     7
```

The result has the `x` and `y` columns extended to match the dimensions of `nestdf`, with the new rows using the existing values. However, I want the new rows to contain NA, like so:

```
#      x     y     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1     3
#2    NA    NA     2     4
#3     3     4     3     5
#4    NA    NA     4     6
#5    NA    NA     5     7
```

Is it possible to do this with `unnest`? Either the first or last row for each group can be kept as non-NA, I don't mind.

Comment: Are you interested in possible non-`unnest` answers?

Comment: that's fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating rows, and binding with an `unnest` of the nested list column(s):

```
nr <- sapply(df$nestdf, nrow) - 1
cbind(
  df[rep(rbind(seq_along(nr), NA), rbind(1, nr)), c("x","y")],
  unnest(df["nestdf"], cols=everything())
)

#   x  y a b
#1  1  2 1 3
#2 NA NA 2 4
#3  3  4 3 5
#4 NA NA 4 6
#5 NA NA 5 7
```

Comment: I've fixed this so that it works if any rows aren't actually duplicated

Comment: Oops, i actually broke it, hang on

Comment: @HongOoi - think I've fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to change the duplicates to `NA`.

```
df1 <- tidyr::unnest(df, nestdf) 
cols <- c('x', 'y')
df1[duplicated(df1[cols]), cols] <- NA
df1

#      x     y     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     1     3
#2    NA    NA     2     4
#3     3     4     3     5
#4    NA    NA     4     6
#5    NA    NA     5     7
```

---

If the values in columns `x` and `y` can repeat you can create a row number to identify them uniquely -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% unnest(nestdf)
cols <- c('x', 'y', 'row')
df1[duplicated(df1[cols]), cols] <- NA
df1 <- select(df1, -row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `x` and `y` to lists first:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~nestdf,
  1,  2,  tibble::tibble(a=1:2, b=3:4),
  3,  4,  tibble::tibble(a=3:5, b=5:7)
)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(x:y), ~map2(., nestdf, ~.x[seq(nrow(.y))])) %>%
  unnest(everything())

# A tibble: 5 x 4
#x     y     a     b
#<dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
#  1     1     2     1     3
#2    NA    NA     2     4
#3     3     4     3     5
#4    NA    NA     4     6
#5    NA    NA     5     7
```